# Como generar un id unico y auto incremental en mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express.js

soy nuevo en mongo, quería saber si se podía generar un id único y auto-incremental en mongodb, asi como en sql. En vez de utilizar el *id* por defecto que genera mongo. Si se puede, como seria? Gracias

Comment: Hola Santiago, te recomiendo leer [éste articulo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.2/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

Comment: ¿Porqué y para qué querrías usar un campo autoincremental?